# VB 2012 - Bindingsource filters to filter ALL columns?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm making a simple vb database app. Loaded my table into a bindingsource, assigned it to a datagridview, and now doing some filtering. I currently have this, which works perfectly :

```
FcscustomersBindingSource.Filter = "address1 like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
```

And if i then tag on "OR address2 like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" , then it successfully searches on both columns. But I have a LOT of columns. is there anyway to filter based on ALL columns without having to make a filter explicitly naming every field?

something like FcscustomersBindingSource.Filter = "* like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ????     I know that's not the right syntax obviously, but my question is, is there a way to simply tell it to filter based on any match in any column?

Comment: No it is not.  There might be ways to make generating the filter more succinct but the filter itself must be explicit.

Comment: I'd just loop through your DataTables Columns generating the filter this way. If doing so you do not need to adjust your filter for each column change